# vim fails to compile on RHEL 9 with clang: file format not recognized

Tags: vim, clang, rhel

I am trying to build the latest version of vim on RHEL 9 using commands that worked successfully on RHEL 8 and RHEL 7.  However the linker complains that it doesn't recognize the file format:

objects/option.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Here are the commands that I used:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/vim
sudo chown $USER /opt/vim
cd /opt/vim
wget https://github.com/vim/vim/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
rm master.zip
cd ./vim-master/src

CC=clang CXX=clang++ CFLAGS= LD=clang LDFLAGS=-rdynamic \
   ./configure --enable-cscope \
               --enable-fail-if-missing \
               --enable-perlinterp=yes \
               --enable-python3interp=yes \
               --enable-terminal \
               --with-python3-command=python3.8

make -j8
sudo make install
```

The "make -j8" command shows the command to compile objects/option.o and that we eventually complain that this file is not recognized when linking:

```
clang -c -I.  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches     -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fwrapv  -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE   -I/home/ztoth/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/include/python3.8 -pthread -fPIE   -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MOTIF     -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1              -o objects/option.o option.c

...

  clang   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1   -rdynamic -L/usr/local/lib       -o vim objects/alloc.o objects/arabic.o objects/arglist.o objects/autocmd.o objects/beval.o objects/buffer.o objects/change.o objects/blob.o objects/blowfish.o objects/cindent.o objects/clientserver.o objects/clipboard.o objects/cmdexpand.o objects/cmdhist.o objects/crypt.o objects/crypt_zip.o objects/debugger.o objects/dict.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/drawline.o objects/drawscreen.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/evalbuffer.o objects/evalfunc.o objects/evalvars.o objects/evalwindow.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/filepath.o objects/findfile.o objects/float.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/gui_xim.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o objects/help.o objects/highlight.o objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/indent.o objects/insexpand.o objects/list.o objects/locale.o objects/logfile.o objects/map.o objects/mark.o objects/match.o objects/mbyte.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/mouse.o objects/move.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/optionstr.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmenu.o objects/popupwin.o objects/profiler.o objects/pty.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/register.o objects/screen.o objects/scriptfile.o objects/search.o objects/session.o objects/sha256.o objects/sign.o objects/sound.o objects/spell.o objects/spellfile.o objects/spellsuggest.o objects/strings.o objects/syntax.o objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/terminal.o objects/testing.o objects/textformat.o objects/textobject.o objects/textprop.o objects/time.o objects/typval.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/usercmd.o objects/userfunc.o objects/version.o objects/vim9class.o objects/vim9cmds.o objects/vim9compile.o objects/vim9execute.o objects/vim9expr.o objects/vim9instr.o objects/vim9script.o objects/vim9type.o objects/viminfo.o objects/window.o objects/bufwrite.o objects/gui.o objects/gui_motif.o objects/gui_x11.o objects/gui_beval.o objects/gui_xmdlg.o objects/gui_xmebw.o objects/vterm_encoding.o objects/vterm_keyboard.o objects/vterm_mouse.o objects/vterm_parser.o objects/vterm_pen.o objects/vterm_screen.o objects/vterm_state.o objects/vterm_unicode.o objects/vterm_vterm.o   objects/if_perl.o objects/if_perlsfio.o  objects/if_python3.o    objects/netbeans.o objects/job.o objects/channel.o objects/xdiffi.o objects/xemit.o objects/xprepare.o objects/xutils.o objects/xhistogram.o objects/xpatience.o  objects/charset.o objects/json.o objects/main.o objects/memfile.o objects/message.o  -lXp -lXmu -lXext -lXm -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE -ldl  -lm -ltinfo -lelf  -lselinux    -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lresolv -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc  -L/home/ztoth/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -ldl -L/home/ztoth/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/ztoth/.pyenv/versions/3.8.18/lib -lm -lm

clang-16: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-16: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-16: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-16: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-16: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-16: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
objects/option.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized

clang-16: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
link.sh: Linking failed
make: *** [Makefile:2058: vim] Error 1
```

Comment: Use Vim's issue tracker.

Comment: I opened the following issue with vim.  Thank you.

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/14012